# How to change the color between 2 characters in richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How to change the color between 2 characters in richtextbox?

I wrote a code like this but this time it doesn't get the last character.

```
        if (e.KeyChar=='"')
        {
            if (richTextBox1.SelectionColor==Color.Black)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (richTextBox1.SelectionColor == Color.Red)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
```

Output: ****"Hello World****"
I get results like this.

**Thanks**

Comment: The question is unclear. What two characters? Where is this code called from? What is the selection? Changing the selection color works. You have to make sure the selection is what you want it to be.

Comment: And, "Output: **"Hello World"** I get results like this. <new-line> **Thanks**" is just about meaningless in the context of this question

Comment: Do you mean to toggle the colors for each character?

Comment: first  characheter is " second character is "  and   Çıktı: **"Merhaba Dünya**"  (") second  charachter is not colorized.

Comment: no, only for specified characters, eg. & Hello world &, the color of the text between &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question not clear but I try to understand  you are trying to give a color in richtextbox value 2 by 2 .

and you wrote your code in richTextBox1_KeyDown

try to code below and change the colors to see what happens.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ss = e.KeyChar; //you can do what you want with this value in your case then 
        if (richTextBox1.TextLength > 0)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.TextLength % 2 == 0)
            {
                if (richTextBox1.SelectionColor == Color.Black)
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else if (richTextBox1.SelectionColor == Color.Red)
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: teşekkür ederim

Comment: Cevap doğruysa yukarıdaki yoruma ok verirsen konu kapansın :)

Comment: kelimelerin 2'nin katı  harflerini yapmış mantık doğru benimde yapmaya çalıştığım bu mantıkta fark olarak  2 karakter arasındaki yazı sadece o renk oluyor son karaktere 2. kere bastığımda ise o karakter de siyah oluyor  örnek: **"merhaba**  " kalın olan yazıyı kırmızı düşün sondaki ( " ) karakteri siyah oluyor. son karakteri bir türlü kırmızı yapamadım :D

Comment: simdi kutucuktan ciktiktan sonra kontrolde saglayabilirsin bunu focuschange eventi altinda yaparsin. veya kutucuga her yazilan harfin rengini degistirirsin; yazilan veyahut basilan tusun son tus oldugunu focus eventi degistiginde ancak anlayabilirsin.
focus change altinda
 richTextBox1 in textLenght ini alirsin son indexteki harfin rengini change edersin.

Comment: Tamam teşekkür ederim. :D